# Why does `Thread` "collapse" my list of truth values when `MapThread` does not?

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation

If I have

```
v1 = RandomInteger[5, 10];
v2 = RandomInteger[5, 10];
Remove[f]
```

then, not surprisingly

```
MapThread[f,{v1,v2}]
%/.f[a_,b_]->a==b
```

gives (for example)

```
{f[5,2],f[4,1],f[3,3],f[3,4],f[1,2],f[3,4],f[1,0],f[3,0],f[4,0],f[1,1]}
{False,False,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,True}
```

and

```
Thread[f[v1,v2]]
%/.f[a_,b_]->a==b
```

gives the same results

```
{f[5,2],f[4,1],f[3,3],f[3,4],f[1,2],f[3,4],f[1,0],f[3,0],f[4,0],f[1,1]}
{False,False,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,True}
```

But if I define

```
f[a_,b_] := a==b
```

then `MapThread` and `Thread` no longer give the same results:

```
MapThread[f,{v1,v2}]
Thread[f[v1,v2]]
```

gives

```
{False,False,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,True}
False
```

What's going on here? Why do the same expressions result in different evaluations? Why does `Thread` "collapse" the list of truth values when `MapThread` does not?

---

Note that a [related example in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) is misleading about what happens here. It shows how

```
Thread[{a,b,c}=={x,y,z}]
```

evaluates to

```
{a==x,b==y,c==z}
```

but that's only true if the elements of the first group can't be compared to the elements of the second.

Comment: `Thread` isn't `Hold*` so `f[v1,v2]` evaluates immediately

Comment: I devoted a separate section to this [in my book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node481.html)